# Using summary(glm-object) inside ldply() with the summarise() - function

Tags: r, extract, plyr, summary, glm

How do i use the summary-function inside a ldply()-summarise-function to extract p-values?

**Example data:**

(The data frame "Puromycin" is preinstalled)

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
Puromycin.m <- melt( Puromycin , id=c("state")  )
Puro.models <-  dlply( Puromycin.m , .(variable)  , glm , formula =  state ~ value  , 
family = binomial  )
```

**I can construct this data frame with extracted results:**

```
ldply( Puro.models  ,  summarise ,  "n in each model" = length(fitted.values) ,   
"Coefficients" = coefficients[2] )
```

**But i cant extract the p-values in the same way. I thougt this would work but it does not:**

```
    ldply( Puro.models  ,  summarise ,  
    "n in each model" = length(fitted.values) , 
    "Coefficients" = coefficients[2], 
    "P-value" = function(x) summary(x)$coef[2,4]              )
```

**How can i extract p-values to that data frame :) Please help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you get them directly?

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
Puromycin.m <- melt( Puromycin , id=c("state")  )
Puro.models <-  ddply( Puromycin.m , .(variable), function(x) {
    t <- glm(x, formula = state ~ value, family="binomial")
    data.frame(n = length(t$fitted.values), 
                coef = coefficients(t)[2], 
                pval = summary(t)$coef[2,4])
})

> Puro.models
#   variable  n        coef      pval
# 1     conc 23 -0.55300908 0.6451550
# 2     rate 23 -0.01555023 0.1272184
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Do you have any suggested reading to get a better understanding of using functions inside ddply() ?

Comment: I like [**this presentation**](https://speakerdeck.com/lowdecarie/hadley-ecosystem-reshape-plyr-ggplot) a lot. It's a very nice initial read. However, I think there is no substitute to [**Hadley's documentation**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf). Hope this helps.